# find most common value with conditions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBmEg.png)
I want to summarize the most common Incoterm in the highlighted cells.
I am not sure why cell F3 shows #N/A.

This is my formula:
{=INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MODE(IF($A$2:$A$19=$E3,IF($B$2:$B$19=F$1,MATCH($C$2:$C$19,$C$2:$C$19,0)))))}

Anybody can help ?
Thanks~

Comment: You will get an error if there isn't a mode and they are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mode requires more than 1 value. In the set you have given there is only 1 value being passed back

```
BCD   BR22  EXW
```

Wrap your formula in an IFERROR or otherwise handle the case of only 1 item being passed to Mode.

Use a variation on the following to return the value when singular:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MATCH(TRUE,CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$19,$B$2:$B$19)=CONCATENATE(E3,F1),0))
```

Might look something like (array formula) as follows, in F2 and dragged, though you can simplify:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$19,$B$2:$B$19)=CONCATENATE($E2,F$1)))>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$28,MODE(IF($A$2:$A$28=$E2,IF($B$2:$B$28=F$1,MATCH($C$2:$C$28,$C$2:$C$28,0))))),INDEX($C$2:$C$19,MATCH(TRUE,CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$19,$B$2:$B$19)=CONCATENATE($E2,F$1),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks~ I had revised my formula as below but shows #VALUE!. =IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A20,E3,B2:B19,F1)=1,VLOOKUP(E3&F1,A1:C19,3,0),INDEX(C2:C19,MODE(IF(A2:A19=E3,IF(B2:B19=F1,MATCH(C1:C2,C2:C19,0))))))

Comment: Hi, you can create an array for the concatenation and index into that searching for true, see edit

Comment: ya done~ btw, may I know whats "--" for ? after "sumproduct"

Comment: It converts the boolean true/false to 1 or 0 so I can then sum the matches for the concatenated values. If there is only 1 match in total then I know I need to x rather than y...

Comment: I see. In raw data, what is I add in another supplier "KSH" and it has two different plants and each plant has one incoterms that are different, then the above formula returns "#N/A". Anyway can help solve this also ? tks

Comment: Again, this would need to be handled by IFERROR as there would be no valid mode... You have one a piece.